# Does a facebook like-box or twitter follow pop up hurt SEO

Tags: seo, facebook, social-media, twitter, pop-up

I have a website with consistent SEO traffic. I would like to display facebook like-box (and/or twitter follow) in a pop up after the user spends certain time (say 5 seconds) on a page. Will such an implementation hurt SEO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unlikely to directly affect your site's SERP performance, but it may indirectly harm it, if:

- It makes your page load more slowly
- It decreases the user's dwell time on your site

A helpful question to to ask if whether it will improve the user's experience on your site, and help them to achieve the goal of their visit.

Comment: Yes I understand that user experience should not be compromised at any cost. However, I would like to know if there is any specific directive from Google or other search engines in relation to pop up.

Comment: You write "I understand that user experience should not be compromised at any cost". It's reasonable to assume that popping up a box 5 seconds after the user visits the page will seriously compromise the user experience!